# Meteor CMS two application or all in one

Tags: node.js, meteor, architecture, content-management-system, software-design

I'm currently working on a CMS for meteor (basically a WordPress-like).

I have a simple question about the design of this CMS.

Should I divide my CMS in two application :

-One part for the viewed content (site, template, viewer plugins)
-Another one for the administration part (statistics, web mastering, post and page creation, etc)

Or,

Should I make an all in one application using different routes and security levels.

From my point of view both have pros and cons.

Divide :

- Share the CMS between several servers.
- Possibility to  manage different websites with only one administration application. Looks like a network.
  -Using administration without the viewer app.(Headless Drupal)
  -Using the full meteor potential for big application.

All in one :

- Smaller application, template more adapted to the administration panel.
- Easier to handling it.
  -Blog oriented.

I'm really interested by your ideas and opinion.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest splitting it up between viewers and admin. You don't want viewers of the site to have to download so much extra code. Both parts can share the same database.